# How to get selected TabBar item?

Tags: ios

I have went through some SO question and found this :

```
NSLog(@"selected tab index => %d",self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.tag);
```

However this is always return 0.
What am I doing wrong?

my code in AppDelegate :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Assign tab bar item with titles
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];    
    return YES;
}
```

Edit :

I would like to do something like this :

```
if(self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.tag == 0)
{
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
}   
else     if(self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.tag == 1)
{
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}
```

Comment: Use `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex`, it will give index of the view controller associated with the currently selected tab item.

Comment: Do you have a navigation controller in your tabs?

Comment: No I use a tab bar controller as in the template project (tab based app)

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the tag value to the item in the Storyboard Editor or programmatically for it to be different from zero.

Comment: I indeed didn't had that however I still can't get the selected tab

Answer (score 2):

Let's try:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
NSLog(@"%d",tabBarController.selectedIndex); //2147483647, will return tab 0
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
NSLog(@"%d",tabBarController.selectedIndex); // will return 1
return YES;
}
```

To get it:

```
//my comment : be sure that self.tabBarController is tabBarController from your appDelegate
if(self.tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0)
{
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
}   
else if(self.tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1)
{
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}
```

Comment: This sets the selectedIndex I would like to get it. So if you press the first tab I would like to get 0 and second tab 1 etc so that I can use a if statement like if(selectedIndex == 0) {//do something}

Answer (score 1):

The original question asked how to get/set the UITabBarItem using the **TAG**. I don't see an actual answer here.

**Tag** ***IS*** the better value to use particularly if you wish to save or "remember" the value so as to be able to restore the "last" selected tab in a future session. The index of any viewController on the TabBar can change if the user re-arranges tabs from the ***More menu***, while tag will not if the App is properly designed.

To get the tag for the currently selected TabBarItem:

```
_tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.tag;
```

To restore/set it from a value:

```
unsigned lastSelectedIndex = [[userSettings objectForKey:SavedTabLastViewedKey] unsignedIntValue];
for(UIViewController *vc in _tabBarController.viewControllers) {
    if(vc.tabBarItem.tag == lastSelectedIndex) {
        _tabBarController.selectedViewController = vc;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should solve this in the storyboard section. Select your UITabBarItem and go to its properties. Go to option "Tag" and set the value (by default all are set to 0 value)